# Appium / selenium: testNG parallel execution not working

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, appium, appium-ios

i am using appium and selenium.
i am trying to rum it parallel (one case after another case)
my first case (forgot password is running properly ) and after that execution is just stop.

can anyone help me with this?

i have attached testng.xml , and testbase file. also login and forgot password scripts.

- i guess there is some issues with annotations.
- i have tried few but now working.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!!!

Here my code looks like:

**1.testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="classes">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0001ForgotPassword" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0002Login" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0003Dashboard" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0004Activity" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0005MoveMoney" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0006InternationalTransfer" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0007Integration" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0008Account" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**2. testbase.java**

```
public class testBase {

    private String reportDirectory = "reports";
    private String reportFormat = "xml";
    private String testName = "Untitled";
    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = null;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
        dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
        dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "afb65172e9b47b01482d912dede58515819748a3");
        dc.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID, "com.novo.ios.dev");
        driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
        driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void teardown() {

    }

}
```

**3.Forgot password**

```
public class TC0001ForgotPassword extends testBase {

    @Test
    public void ForgotPassword() throws InterruptedException {

        // Test case for blank email address.

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Forgot Password?']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys("Automationtesting@banknovo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Done']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CONFIRM']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='(MM/DD/YYYY)']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Done']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CONFIRM']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='2']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='3']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='4']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CONFIRM']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CONFIRM']")).sendKeys("111111");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CONFIRM']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("Novo@2019");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Confirm Password']")).sendKeys("Novo@2019");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("(//*[@class='UIAView' and ./parent::*[@class='UIAScrollView']]/*[@text='icEyeOpen'])[1]"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='icEyeOpen']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='RESET PASSWORD']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='DONE']")).click();

    }
```

**4. Login**

```
package com.live.testcase;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.live.common.testBase;

public class TC0002Login extends testBase {

    @Test
    public void TC000001_Blank_Email_Password() {

        // Test case for blank email address.
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();
    }

    @Test
    public void TC000002_Invailid_Email() throws Exception {

        // Test case for invalid email addresses
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys("automationtesting");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("Novo");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();

    }

    @Test
    public void TC000003_Invailid_Password() throws Exception {

        // Test case for invalid email addresses
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("Novo@2019");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();

    }

    @Test
    public void TC000004_Valid_Email_Password() throws Exception {
        // Test case for Valid email addresses & password
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys("automationtesting@banknovo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("Novo@2019");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
    }
}
```

**5. pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.novo.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.novo.app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this could be the issue:
You instruct testng to run parallel at suite tag not at test tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="5" parallel="classes">
    <test  name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0001ForgotPassword" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0002Login" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0003Dashboard" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0004Activity" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0005MoveMoney" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0006InternationalTransfer" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0007Integration" />
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0008Account" />
        </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Comment: No mate, it throw same error. as per your comment. you have just change the order of test.It won't help. Thanks for comment. Let me know if you have any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Parallelism and time-outs](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) chapter:

> The parallel attribute on the `<suite>` tag can take one of following values:
>
> `<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">`
>
> `<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">`
>
> `<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">`
>
> `<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">`

So my expectation is that you need to amend your [testng.xml](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" configfailurepolicy="continue" verbose="2">
    <test name="TC0001ForgotPassword">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0001ForgotPassword"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0002Login">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0002Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0003Dashboard">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0003Dashboard"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0004Activity">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0004Activity"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0005MoveMoney">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0005MoveMoney"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0006InternationalTransfer">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0006InternationalTransfer"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0007Integration">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0007Integration"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TC0008Account">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.live.testcase.TC0008Account"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

More information including sample project: [Parallel Tests Execution](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+Execution)

Comment: Hey, i have tried above code but its not working. can you please check the video link - https://www.loom.com/share/a0f6fc59f0a8413898f8ec76fd756041